# Multipy character position by ord() value of that character

Tags: python, substring, ord

I'm trying to make a function in python that would take a word, find ASCII value of each character in a word, **then multiply each of the value by the position of the character in that word** and sum together.
I came up with below however I don't know how to multiply each 'x' with the position number of each char.

```
mystring = 'AZC'
total = 0
for c in mystring:
    x = ord(c)
    total += x
print(total)
```

this code returns value 222 (65 for 'A' + 90 for 'Z' + 67 for 'C') but I need 65 * 1 + 90 * 2 + 66 * 3 = 443
It will probably have something to do with substring but I am lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `enumerate()` to get the positions. And you can use the `sum()` function to add them all together.

```
total = sum(pos * ord(c) for pos, c in enumerate(mystring, 1))
```

The second argument `1` makes it start the positions at `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: This is fantastic and clean looking! Could you give me a hint on how could I apply this to a df colum? So that 'mystring' was df['mystring'] and the total would be df['total']?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know pandas well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to know the index of the character

```
for index, c in enumerate(mystring):
    x = ord(c)
    pos = index + 1
    total += (x * pos)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mystring = 'AZC'
total = 0
for i,c in enumerate(mystring):
    x = ord(c)
    total += (x*(i+1))
print(total)
```

`enumerate` returns a tuple having the position as well as the element over which you are iterating.